# Equivalent code using java streams for conventional for loop

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I need to convert this `for` loop code using Java streams:

```
boolean present = false;
for (Long studentKey : studentKeys) {
    if (!studentKey.equals(student.getId())) {
        present= true;
        log.debug(STR_SESSION_BLOCKED_ANOTHER_USER);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, go ahead! What prevents you from doing this? (You may want to read [ask].)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above equivalent code returns me the correct boolean flag

```
    boolean present = studentKeys.stream() .anyMatch(key -> 
    !key.equals(student.getId())); 
    if(present) log.debug(STR_SESSION_BLOCKED_ANOTHER_USER);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following instructions:

- Create your stream instance which includes the `if` condition: `studentKeys.stream().filter(key -> !key.equals(student.getId()))`
- Nest your stream inside a supplier instance (class `java.util.function.Supplier`). Indeed, every stream instance can only be treated once and the supplier enables to re-create a new instance each time we need it.
- Do the required actions with your stream (`present` and `log.debug`).

The following code would be like this:

```
Supplier<Stream<Long>> studentFilter = () ->
        studentKeys.stream().filter(key -> !key.equals(student.getId()));

boolean present = (studentFilter.get().count() != 0L);
studentFilter.get().forEach(key -> log.debug(STR_SESSION_BLOCKED_ANOTHER_USER));
```

Comment: After calling `filteredStudentKeys.count()`, the stream is closed. Error will thrown when calling `forEach`.

Comment: I'm forgot that in Java, every stream can be used only once. I will update the solution using the `Supplier` class.

Comment: Instead of running over *all* elements and count them, just to find out if there is at least *one*, you can use `.anyMatch(x -> true)` instead of `.count() != 0L`. Given that there is no advantage in potentially repeating the same log message multiple times, you can simply use `boolean present = studentKeys.stream() .anyMatch(key -> !key.equals(student.getId())); if(present) log.debug(STR_SESSION_BLOCKED_ANOTHER_USER);`. I suppose, the original loop author’s intention was the same and they simply forgot a `break;`

Comment: @Holger you're right, I thought the same thing about the `break` statement but didn't take it into account for the solution. I've kept a "similar" code behaviour

Comment: @hogler it worked